# How to bind a combo box datasource to a form/listbox in windows forms?

Tags: winforms, combobox

[image: Combo box datasource as form/listbox]

I would like to get the form as datasource when i click combo box. How could i achieve this. Please give suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a PopupComboBox class which inherits from the standard Windows Forms ComboBox. It has a Title property that you can set which will be used on the popup window when the combo is clicked.

```
public class PopupComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        private string title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return this.title; }
            set { this.title = value; }
        }
        public PopupComboBox() : base()
        {

        }

        public PopupComboBox (string title)
            : base()
        {
            this.title = title;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseClick(e);

            // Show the popup form
            var popup = new SelectItemForm(this.title, this);
            var result = popup.ShowDialog(this);

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Select this item in the ComboBox
                SelectedIndex = this.FindStringExact(popup.SelectedDisplay);
            }
        }
    }
```

When you click on the combo, a popup form will come up (source code below for SelectItemForm). It uses the DataSource, ValueMember and DisplayMember of the parent PopupComboBox to populate a ListView with the list of items from the combo. When you click on OK, it will save the selected item in the SelectedValue and SelectedDisplay properties so that we can select that item in the ComboBox when the form closes.

[image: The popup form]

```
public partial class SelectItemForm : Form
    {
        public object SelectedValue { get; private set; }
        public string SelectedDisplay { get; private set; }

        public SelectItemForm(string title, PopupComboBox parent)
            :base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Text = title;

            // Add items to the list
            foreach (var item in parent.Items)
            {
                // Get the display and value member properties for this combo box
                // and use them for the Code/Name columns in the popup form
                var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();
                var code = props.Where(p => p.Name == parent.ValueMember).Single().GetValue(item);
                var name = props.Where(p => p.Name == parent.DisplayMember).Single().GetValue(item);

                listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
                    new string[] { code.ToString(), name.ToString() }));
            }
        }

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listView.SelectedItems != null && listView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                SelectedValue = listView.SelectedItems[0].Text;
                SelectedDisplay = listView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;

                DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Select an item first", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        }
    }
```

Here is the designer part of the form, where you can see what properties I've changed for the ListView to look like it does:

```
partial class SelectItemForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.listView = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
            this.btnOk = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnCancel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.Code = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
            this.Value = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // listView
            // 
            this.listView.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.listView.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
            this.Code,
            this.Value});
            this.listView.FullRowSelect = true;
            this.listView.GridLines = true;
            this.listView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            this.listView.MultiSelect = false;
            this.listView.Name = "listView";
            this.listView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(432, 170);
            this.listView.TabIndex = 0;
            this.listView.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            this.listView.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
            // 
            // btnOk
            // 
            this.btnOk.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.btnOk.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(272, 179);
            this.btnOk.Name = "btnOk";
            this.btnOk.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnOk.TabIndex = 1;
            this.btnOk.Text = "OK";
            this.btnOk.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnOk.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnOk_Click);
            // 
            // btnCancel
            // 
            this.btnCancel.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.btnCancel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(353, 179);
            this.btnCancel.Name = "btnCancel";
            this.btnCancel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnCancel.TabIndex = 2;
            this.btnCancel.Text = "Cancel";
            this.btnCancel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnCancel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnCancel_Click);
            // 
            // Code
            // 
            this.Code.Text = "Code";
            this.Code.Width = 108;
            // 
            // Value
            // 
            this.Value.Text = "Name";
            this.Value.Width = 296;
            // 
            // SelectItemForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(440, 214);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnCancel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnOk);
            this.Controls.Add(this.listView);
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "SelectItemForm";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            this.Text = "Title";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnOk;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnCancel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader Code;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader Value;
    }
```

I've also created a small test form where you can test out the functionality of the PopupComboBox, using a small list of products. You'll need to add a PopupComboBox to the form in the designer, and call it comboPopup.

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
    {
        public class Product
        {
            public string Code { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public TestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var products = new List<Product>();
            products.Add(new Product { Code = "0001", Name = "Coca Cola" });
            products.Add(new Product { Code = "0002", Name = "Mountain Dew" });
            products.Add(new Product { Code = "0003", Name = "Sprite Zero" });

            comboPopup.DataSource = products;
            comboPopup.DisplayMember = "Name";
            comboPopup.ValueMember = "Code";

        }
    }
```